# VS2010 hanging a lot lately. Should I try SP1 beta?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

VS2010 start hanging in some dummy operations like paste, scrolling, opening a file ([video](http://screencast.com/t/Vm9Edie86hH)). Very frustrating.
I've disabled all extensions, but still no luck.

Is SP1 beta stable enough to take a chance on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally installed SP1 beta. So far no hangings, It seams that VS2010 SP1 handle the errors better before completely crashing (even when is extension related)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have those issues myself.  Taking a glance over the [issues list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/12/20/visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta-feedback.aspx) I don't see anything particularly related to that.  In fact, the performance feedback is being requested with some details.  Check the link.

> We continue to see a lot of feedback
>   on performance in particular which we
>   would like to correlate with machine
>   configs and project types.  If you can
>   send your performance related issues
>   to devperf@microsoft.com we want to do
>   more investigation of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'd always prefer reinstalling the RTM over using a beta for production code.

Comment: I don't have big hopes that a reinstall will solve the issues, and don't have time for a complete repav.